# How to refactor method to show value if true, false or both?

Tags: java, refactoring

I got a method signature like this.

```
List<CngCollectionStatement> findCollectionStatements(Boolean posted);
```

As we all know boolean, enum will give you a finite value. For example boolean will give true or false.

So this method will return either record with true or false. What if we want to display both of them? I mean to display all the records?

What is the best practice for this problem?

Comment: You are using `Boolean`, not `boolean`. That means you can pass `null`. But I would recommend using an `enum` with constants `POSTED`, `NOT_POSTED`, `ALL`.

Comment: I am trying to avoid null in this case

Comment: If you don't want to pass `null` (or an empty Optional) here, you could also have two separate methods (one that filters and one that does not). They may still dispatch to the same private method down the line to avoid duplication in their implementations.

Comment: @Thilo 
Are you recommend something like 
`List<CngCollectionStatement> findUnpostedCollectionStatements();`
`List<CngCollectionStatement> findPostedCollectionStatements();`

Comment: Questions about refactoring working code are off-topic for stack overflow. Try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't want to speak about best practice without seeing the rest of your methods. Do you have other filters as well? Can those be combined? How about sorting? Passing `null/Optional.empty` for "no need to filter" is what I usually do.

Comment: Just this simple method. Without any sorting or pagination
@Thilo that's what I did for now

Answer (score 1):

Boolean flag as parameter makes code less readable. I would recommend to split your method into 3 separate methods with more specific names:

```
findPostedStatements()
findUnpostedStatements()
findAllStatements()
```

Answer (score 0):

Though `Set<Boolean>` seems what you intend, imho it seems a bit of a kludge.

So:

```
List<CngCollectionStatement> findCollectionStatements(boolean posted, boolean unposted);
```

Comment: What if I used enum as the parameter? What you recommend?

Comment: That would be **clearest**, Personally I would do it when at least another API call would benefit from it, or there were more parameters. Or the internal code would benefit from it (an enum can have public final fields differing from POSTED, UNPOSTED, ALL). Also `(false, false)` seem undesirable.